# Please enable MathJax

Tags: support, status-declined, mathjax

Already I needed it more than once for [my answer](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/a/156/34) to: [What are the disadvantages of not handling big numbers?](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/125/34)

Comment: Adding MathJax to Stack Overflow has been discussed several times and rejected each time. For math-specific sites like Math.SE and Math Overflow, I get it. But I feel like we need MathJax about as often as SO does, so if they don't have it, I doubt we'll get it.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I completely disagree. SO gets 3.6k visits/day, 6 million visits/day, and has 24 million questions in total, so they are concerned about MathJax slowing down the site. The site with the second largest number of questions is Mathematics SE, which has 10x fewer questions/day, and 60x fewer visits/day, and the site is ***full of MathJax***. This site is expected to have 100x fewer questions/day and 1000x fewer visits/day compared to Mathematics.SE. MathJax will not slow down the site the way it would for SO. What other reason could there be to avoid enabling MathJax?

Comment: Adding MathJax only has performance impacts on the *client* side, not the server side. The volume/traffic *does not matter at all*. Just think of it as 'every page needs X% longer to load'. Yes, MathJax would be useful for that answer, but it seems like anecdotal evidence (N=1) ...

Comment: @NikeDattani `SO gets 3.6k visits/day, 6 million visits/day` How is that supposed to work?

Comment: @Glorfindel can you suggest any reason why MathJax should not be enabled?

Comment: Like I said; if every page takes X% longer to load for you (and other users), is that worth the improvement to Y% of the posts? I don't know the exact values for X and Y, but if Y is negligible, MathJax should not be enabled. I know both X and Y are hard to determine, but have you found *another* post here which would *significantly* benefit from MathJax?

Comment: @user16217248 3.6k is *questions* per day - stats are taken from [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites)

Comment: @Glorfindel what do you think is more likely to be negligible: X or Y? Hint: Math.SE has 1.6 million questions.

Comment: The total amount of questions *does not matter at all* - it's the amount of posts which benefits vs. the total amount of posts. Yes, supporting MathJax is possible, even on large sites. If Math.SE was larger than SO, it still wouldn't be enabled on SO.

Comment: @Glorfindel You said that "the total amount of questions *does not matter at all*" and then immediately after that you said that what matters is "the total amount of posts". The total number posts is a function of the total number of questions. Anyway, what do you think is more likely to be negligible: X or Y?

Comment: As you've given only one example, Y is negligible on this site. I don't know about X, except that it's significant; otherwise, MathJax would be enabled on all sites. The total amount of posts/questions does not matter; X and Y are *ratios*.

Comment: @Glorfindel Y=1 does not necessarily mean that it's negligible, and me giving only 1 example does not necessarily mean that Y=1. But anyway, I suggest that you determine the value of X before concluding that it's significant. The fact that some sites don't have MathJax does not mean that X is significant.

Comment: I've asked you for more than 1 example already. MathJax is useful on some Stack Overflow posts (probably on more posts than there will ever be on this site), yet it's not enabled. I'm not opposed to enabling MathJax here, I just want to make sure it's worth it and I'm not convinced (yet).

Comment: @Glorfindel Considering that this post has been upvoted 15 times, which is the second largest number of upvotes on any Meta question on this site so far, and considering that I have other things to do, I have not opened all other posts on this site to check if there's more examples. Do you find that SO loads faster for you than Math.SE?

Comment: Users upvote things even if they don't know the consequences / downsides. I've spent a couple of days on the Appalachian Trail last month, so I know what the benefits of saving a couple of hundred kilobytes are (even with browser caching). I did try to [search for other posts that might benefit](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22%5E%22) but the Stack Exchange search engine doesn't let me and SEDE isn't up to date yet.

Comment: I agree that a lot of users upvote without knowing the consequences/downsides. There's also a lot of users that downvote or refrain from voting, without knowing the consequences/downsides. I appreciate that you experienced a slow connection while on that trail, but then you talked about saving a couple hundred kilobytes, whereas a post by Andrew Morton says that MathJax can be configured with an overhead of just 3.7kB. Also, I assume that your answer to the question in my last comment is: "No it doesn't right now, but it might have when I was out hiking last month, but I don't know" ?

Comment: Does [this post](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/51398/14426) warrant enabling MathJax on Writing.SE? And I'd appreciate a link to that Andrew Morton post ... And remember, it's not just the downloading, also the time that it takes your browser to render stuff. And your last sentence is correct, but let's not forget about more than half of the world which doesn't have access to fast internet (or up to date computers).

Comment: @Glorfindel How did you find that?! As cool as that is, I believe it's a discussion that is more appropriate on the Meta site of Writing.SE.

Comment: [This one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396502/4751173), right? I found that Writing post [via SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/writers/query/1752362). If it's possible to enable MathJax network-wide without any significant consequences, I'm all for it. But unlike syntax highlighting, MathJax is just not an essential feature for this particular site.

Comment: As requested, [here's the Andrew Morton post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396502/1271772). I do agree that people in other parts of the world who don't have fast internet, need to be considered. But Andrew's post or one of the "related" posts, says that it will only affect posts that actually contain MathJax, and the #1 opposer to MathJax (Nick Carver) shows that it only made at most a 2x time difference in 2013. Also, what about imgur images? Should we not allow them because they slow things down?

Comment: Yeah, I found that. My main reason for considering this FR carefully is [unnecessary software bloat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bloat). Without clear figures for X (perhaps worth a Meta.SE post) and Y (currently 0.2%, but I'm open to new examples), I don't think we can reach a definitive conclusion :) At least, the Y for images (imgur or not) is much higher (across the network, perhaps this particular site could do without images).

Comment: I think that what we can at least agree that, 1) it's important for users with slow internet connections to be considered, 2) Nick Carver's study in 2013 showed that Math.SE loaded 2x slower than SO, and SO with MathJax loaded negligiblyslower than SO without MathJax, 3) hardware, software, and internet connections have gotten faster since 2013 but this may have unevenly improved things for people in rich countries compared to in poor countries, 4) whether a page takes 2 seconds to load vs 1 second to load (which was the case in Nick Carver's 2013 study) isn't much (other things can cause it).

Comment: Just for more completeness, I'll list some of the other posts from Writing.SE that arose from the above SEDE query: https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/54254/44466, https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/7625/44466, https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/37910/44466. That might be all of them for now, but the thought of listing these here only arose after I noticed (to my surprise) how many other examples existed.

Comment: One more post that needs it: https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/a/1036/89

Comment: @kaya3 perhaps you can write an answer? With the only answer being a "maybe" and the comments not being favorable, it's unlikely that the proposal will be approved. It might be unbelievable that SE would not approve the enabling of MathJax, but see here: https://cardano.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12/149 (it doesn't yet say status-completed).

Comment: I think the (currently) 19 upvotes to 1 downvote shows that the community wants this. I could write a short answer saying "yes, please add MathJax", but it won't get more upvotes than the question.

Comment: @kaya3 I agree that it's what the community wants, but it was also the case here: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/361/5 and 100% of the comments and answers were in favor of it, including by two elected diamond moderators, and still the proposal was rejected.

Comment: @Catija this user's question was severely affected by MathJaX not being enabled: https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/1045/34 if you're not going to allow it on this site, can you please tell us the reason?

Comment: @Glorfindel If you are worried about performance issues then you could restrict MathJax to only those characters which map to the Unicode character set. For example if the input is `$\mathbb{R}$` then the output would be `ℝ`. If people write `$x_{16}$` then the end result would be `x₁₆ `. Most webpages contain lots of unicode characters which load quickly. Unicode is faster to load than **LaTeX** or ***MathJax***. Additional examples are as follows: (Example 3 (INPUT `$**\neq**$`) (OUTPUT `≠`) ) and (Example 4 (INPUT `$\Sigma$`) (OUTPUT `**Σ**`) )

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon also, it was only rejected 1 time by Nick Craver 10 years ago when computers and browsers were slower. After that requests to add MathJax were just ignored, not rejected. There's way more upvotes on the request to add MathJax, than on Nick Craver's explanation of why he was rejecting it, and it seems that there's only one other person (named Makoto) opposed to using MathJax, and their reason is not very strong.

Answer (score 19):

## I concur.

MathJax would be useful for this site. Most posts won't need it, but some will, and having MathJax will make the site more attractive to academics interested in programming languages.

Comment: Agreed—it can be added through a third-party extension or userscript, but that’s not helpful for new users. When I’ve needed math rendering so far, I’ve written the MathJax LaTeX that I _want_ to write in a comment (`<!--` … `-->`) followed by a Markdown/HTML approximation. So if we get first-party support, my posts are ready to upgrade! The [MathJax demo](https://www.mathjax.org/#demo) serves as a preview/scratchpad.

Answer (score 18):

<s>Since Stack Exchange staff have said this will only be enabled if we can show sufficiently many posts which would use MathJax if it was enabled, let's build a list of such posts on this site.</s>

**MathJax is now enabled!** If you want to be helpful, please make appropriate edits to improve the mathematics formatting in these posts. (Use `<s>` tags to mark posts which have been edited.)

- <s>https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/156</s>
- <s>https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/438</s>
- <s>https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/856</s>
- <s>https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/868</s>
- <s>https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/914</s>
- <s>https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/1036</s>
- <s>https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/1188</s>
- <s>[Can something like a Donkey Sentence exist in a programming language?](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/q/1461)</s>
- <s>[How to avoid hidden performance problems in functional interfaces?](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/q/1549)</s>
- <s>https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/1585</s>
- <s>https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/1696</s>
- <s>https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/1697</s>
- <s>https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/1780</s>
- <s>[How can we define a denotational semantics for recursive functions?](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/q/1953)</s>
- <s>https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/1954</s>
- <s>https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/2021</s>
- <s>https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/2083</s>
- <s>https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/2363</s>
- <s>https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/2429</s>
- <s>https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/2489</s>

  - https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/2544
  - https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/2647
- <s>https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/2652</s>
- <s>https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/2684</s>

Answer (score 5):

### Maybe

The main place where it's going to help a lot is a question or answer that's heavy in theory. Some examples:

- Formal verification and synthesis, such as synthesising instruction selection templates from machine descriptions, proof-carrying code, and understanding the JVM bytecode loader.
- The more mathematical aspects of compiler implementation, such as flow analysis, lattice theory, and the thorny question of what floating point optimisations are "safe".
- Anything to do with formal languages and types, such as the theory behind LR parsers, type inference algorithms, and understanding the syntax of ALGOL 68 (IYKYK).

There are plenty of questions in this space that would be on topic. But so far, questions like this seem rare.

Comment: Is there any reason why you would ***not*** want MathJax enabled?

Comment: I presume that if there were no downsides, it would be enabled in more places. I hope someone explains that.

Comment: @Pseudonym I believe it has to do with resource/bandwidth consumption, I think for SE not for users.

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms I figured it was something like that. So I stand by my answer of "maybe". It wouldn't be useless, but the number of questions/answer that it would be very useful for is tiny right now.

Comment: @Pseudonym I think that *10+ years ago* the decision for it to not automatically load across all pages in each site was indeed due to resource/bandwidth consumption, and page load time for users. A lot as changed on both server and client side (fixed or mobile) both in bandwidth and hardware. I'm not sure loading mathjax automatically has the same impact it did back when SE was first designed.

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms ditto.

Answer (score 3):

[Adin Falkoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adin_Falkoff), an IBM programming systems designer, [said](https://www.jsoftware.com/papers/apl360history.htm):

> programming and mathematics are inseparable

It is certainly reasonable to use mathematical formulas to describe behavior and characteristics of programming constructs. In fact, IBM's System/360 (which developed into today's z/Architecture, and arguably is the forebearer of all modern computing systems) was formally described using a mathematical notation.

Comment: wouldn't this equally be an argument to enable MathJax on SO? (and yet it isn't for other reasons, so are you implying that those other reasons don't apply here?)

Comment: @starball what are the reasons?

Comment: @NikeDattani performance is a big one. need is another. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252282/11107541, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396502/11107541, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356171/11107541

Comment: @starball (1) Why did you include the second link? Just to show that there's only 1 user (Makoto) other than Nick Craver, who combined are the only two people who have written answers against enabling MathJax on SO? (2) "need" is not a reason "not" to enable MathJax, it looks like you're double counting here: either there's enough need for the performance hit to be worth it, or there's not enough need for the performance hit to be worth it ... these would fall under 1 reason not 2. (3) As for performance, can you provide the data requested in the following comment please?

Comment: ^ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252282/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on#comment958166_252283

Answer (score -14):

At this time, we are declining the request to enable MathJax. Given that there seems to be a healthy amount of debate on its merits and the value it may or may not bring, I think we need to give this one a bit more time.

While I understand that some questions might benefit from it, I am hesitant to enable something that can impact page performance this early in the site's existence without a strong need demonstrated.

I want to revisit this topic in public beta when a more concrete need has been demonstrated.

Comment: How can such a "concrete need" be demonstrated? The posts which need MathJax are the ones that can't be written until it is enabled, or at least can't be written the way the author would want to write them, but we can't demonstrate the need by pointing at posts which don't exist. If there is some criterion that this will be judged on when we're in public beta, please tell us what that criterion will be.

Comment: I don't think a "criterion" is the best way to decide this, because people can "game" the criterion by asking a bunch of formal language theory questions until we reach the minimum number of MathJax posts. Instead, the decision should be based on what the community wants, rather than what people who don't plan to post any questions/answers on the site think that we want. Another problem with not including MathJax during Private beta, is that this is a time to experiment and learn what we want on the Public version of the site. We can't do that if we can't ask the more mathematical questions.

Comment: @NikeDattani Absolutely agreed ─ the decision should be based on what the community wants, not on what SE staff decide we need. Even so, if the decision is going to be based on us "demonstrating a concrete need", I think we need to know how that is supposed to work. As far as I can see, it is impossible to demonstrate such a need, because a lack of posts using MathJax isn't evidence we need MathJax. If not an objective criterion, perhaps SpencerG can describe some hypothetical scenarios in which he can imagine that the need for MathJax would be demonstrated.

Comment: John Purdy wanted to use MathJax in at least 44% of his 9 answers: see this https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/a/438/34 and https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/a/1188/34, and click on "edit" to see the comments that he left in https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/a/868/34, and https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/posts/914/edit (there might be more that I missed). In terms of demonstrating a need, ***we should be the ones judging whether or not there's a need for it or if the 0.1 seconds delay in loading is a concern***. We can establish a criteria among ourselves.

Comment: I understand the frustration, folks, but we're treating this request in exactly the same way we've been treating similar requests in the past. An example: [Blender requested MathJax be turned on](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/690/13499); we originally declined the request (providing reasoning), and [asked for many examples of where it would be useful](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2238/13499); [the community compiled those examples](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2224/13499); and [we then turned MathJax on](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2453/13499).

Comment: While an absolute threshold to be achieved has never been formally defined, pointing to just a handful of (or less) posts as justification for enabling this has generally been insufficient for us to do so. Discussion like the one we're having here has always been a part of the process, which generally entails the community _showing_ that there _is_ a need for the feature, not _predicting_ there _will be_.

Comment: It's not true that this is being treated exactly like it was for other sites. See Matter Modeling and Proof Assistants. We've also given at least 6 examples already. Let us decide what we want. If there's a performance hit, it's a client-side one and it's for us to worry about.

Comment: [We ask again.](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/518/269)